# Operation buffering timed out after 10000ms even DB is connected

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I can't find what I'm doing wrong. I already dug through a plethora of stacksoverflows but didn't find any solution.
I constantly getting `` MongooseError: Operation `users.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms `` whenever I try to register a user. Some solutions say that I didn't connect to DATABASE. However, I get a confirm that the DB is connected successfully.
Here is the codes.

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

// Init Middleware
app.use(express.json({ extended: false }));
app.use(cors());

// Bodyparser
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

// Connecting to mongoose
mongoose.connect(
  process.env.REACT_APP_MONGO_URI,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  },
  () => {
    console.log("Connected successfully to DB!");
    // Listening for actions
    app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`));
  }
);

// Defined Routes
app.use("/", require("./routes/index"));
app.use("/users", require("./routes/users"));
```

**users.js**

```
const router = express.Router();
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

const User = require("../models/User");

router.get("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Login");
});

router.get("/register", (req, res) => {
  res.send("Register");
});

// @route  POST /register
// @desc   Creates a user
// @access Public
router.post("/register", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name, surname, email, password, repeatedPassword } = req.body;

    if (!name || !surname || !email || !password || !repeatedPassword) {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Not all fields were filled." });
    }

    if (password !== repeatedPassword) {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: "Password doesn't match." });
    }

    if (password.length < 6) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ msg: "Password should be at least 6 characters long." });
    }

    /*
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: email });
    if (user) {
      return res
        .status(400)
        .json({ msg: "This email is already specified by another user." });
    }
    */
    const newUser = new User({
      name,
      surname,
      email,
      password,
    });
    newUser.save();
    console.log(newUser);
    res.json(newUser);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).send("Server error");
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

**User.js** (model)

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const UserSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  surname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

include user model and create one.

`const User = require('./User')`

`await User.create({ name, surname, email, password, })`

Comment: If you mean by replacing ```const newUser = new User...``` and ```newUser.save....``` with just ```await User.create...``` it throws me a server error